# Compressing with Java Decompressing with PHP

Tags: java, php, gzip, gzipoutputstream

I have a situation where a servlet is providing compressed data to a PHP script. I compress the data on the Java side no problem, but PHP seems unable to decompress.

Here is the relevent code snippets
  Java Side:

```
  OutputStream o=response.getOutputStream();

GZIPOutputStream gz=new GZIPOutputStream(o);
gz.write(GridCoder.encode(rs,id, perPage, page).getBytes());
gz.close();
o.close();
```

PHP Side:

```
$xml= gzuncompress($xml);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you get errors? can you post the logs?

Comment: Make sure your java code is setting the `Content-Encoding: gzip` HTTP header.

Comment: Warning: gzuncompress(): data error. I've tried just echoing the data without trying to decompress it to ensure I'm getting actual data and I get a block of data that starts :�������[
Content Content-Encoding is set to gZip on the Java Side..

Answer (score 11):

I just saw your question and was curious about it. So i made my own test-case. I left all the Servlet related stuff out of the problem and coded something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZIPTestcase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/malax/foo2.gz")));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(gzipOutputStream);

        pw.println("All your base are belong to us!");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

The GNU gunzip was able to uncompress the data. Then i tries to uncompress it with PHP. It failed with the same error you got. I investigated further and found the following methods:

- gzdecode()
- gzinflate()

gzinflate does not work either, gzdecode is only shipped with PHP6 wich i havn't installed. Maybe you could try this. (According to http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22123 this will work)

Im i doubt that the problem is on the Java side because GNU's gunzip can deflate the data so it must be correct. You might want to investigate further on the PHP side.

There is a realted question for .NET and PHP where the original poster has the same problem as you have: [Can PHP decompress a file compressed with the .NET GZipStream class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905328/can-php-decompress-a-file-compressed-with-the-net-gzipstream-class). PHP does not seem to be able to decompress the data from the .NET equivalent of the GZIPOutputStream either.

Sorry that i dont have a "solution" but i might have pointed you in the right direction anyways.

EDIT: I found an entry in the PHP Bugtracker which explains the problem:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22967 It seems that gzuncompress cannot uncompress GZIP data with headers which will be produced be the GZIPOutputStream. As stated in the Bugtracker Entry, try to crop the header.

Answer (score 6):

Try using DeflaterOutputStream instead of GZIPOutputStream

The PHP functions call into libzlib which implements DEFLATE. Gzip is a different beast entirely.

Naming the PHP functions gz*XXX* only adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to fix it, using post by Devon_C_Miller and Malax as a guidelines.

Code for java:

```
   String body = "Lorem ipsum shizzle ma nizle";

   URL url = new URL("http://some.url/file.php?id=" + uid);
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "deflate");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

   DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

   dos.write(body.getBytes());
   dos.flush();
   dos.close();
```

PHP side:

```
   $content = http_get_request_body();

   $uncontent = gzuncompress($content);
```

Comment: +1. I tried many solutions, including which 'to cut the header unrecognized by PHP', but only this worked. thanks.

Comment: that doesn't work with strings that have after compression > 300b ... have no idea why, but in those cases `DeflaterOutputStream` acts like `GZIPOutputStream` (giving same results, undecompressable by PHP)

Comment: @FlashThunder I can't reproduce your problem using PHP 5.6.15 & Java 8. I'm able to gzuncompress() in PHP a 1 million character long random text UTF-8 string compressed with a Java DeflaterOutputStream (using similar to firebear's answer). That's 300KB compressed, and 1MB compressed - far in excess of your 300b. Here's the code used to test your bug: https://gist.github.com/cordje/48a957333cd045afa3792c82334d9b06

Answer (score 2):

The combination of 'Java Deflater + [PHP gzuncompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php)' worked for me. Client: Android 4.1.1, server site: php 5.3

For whom is looking for solution of compressing only parts of the request body in some cases, for example as me, using HTTP form to post some parameters and a file, the following is the snippet I used in Android side:

```
    public static byte[] compressString(String data) throws IOException {
        byte[] compressed = null;
        byte[] byteData = data.getBytes();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteData.length);
        Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
        compressor.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        compressor.setInput(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
        compressor.finish();

        // Compress the data
        final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        while (!compressor.finished()) {
            int count = compressor.deflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        compressor.end();
        compressed = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();
        return compressed;
    }
```